# Excel Pivot Table - work with boolean fields

Tags: sql, excel

I'm fairly new to pivot table and I'm trying to show some statistics from data stored in a MSSQL table.
It's working great so far except that I have a lot of PASS/FAIL columns that contain either TRUE or FALSE (type is 'bit' in MSSQL) and I would like to display a PASS percentage.

I've tried adding calculated fields to convert this to 0/1 but I'm hitting a wall. Google did not help neither.

Comment: can you post the query you tried and some info about different columns you like to project,group or filter

Comment: passfail is one of those boolean fields, I tried to Insert a Calculated Field:

`Name: PASS

Formula: =IF(passfail='TRUE',1,0)` [link](http://i.imgur.com/8DZocnI.png)

Comment: =IF(passfail='TRUE',1,0) in which application are using this, normally in SQL you would do something like select case when passfail =((1)) then 1 else 0 end as tf

Comment: Maybe I was not clear but I have no issue with the query itself, the data is there, however it seems Pivot Tables don't have the tools to deal with booleans.